# plotting "donut" polygons with holes

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I want to make donut-like filled polygons in `ggplot2`, with the centers transparent. I thought that the best approach would be to put the outer an inner polygons into one shape, with a "stem" joining the two polygons, and to then fill this shape. (Imagine like the stem you would have to draw if you had to draw two concentric circles without lifting a pen off of the page.)  See the example below. The problem, though, is that it still fills the interior of the polygon! Does anybody know why this is happening?

```
library(ggplot2)

#generates a dataframe of points for a regular polygon, with the starting point duplicated at the end. 
NgonPoints <- function(center=c(0,0), radius=1, nsides=100, start=0, end=2)
{
  tt <- seq(start*pi, end*pi, length.out=nsides+1)
  data.frame(x = round(center[1] + radius * cos(tt),5), 
             y = round(center[2] + radius * sin(tt),5))
}

#get points for an inner and outer square
twosquares <- rbind(NgonPoints(nsides=4, radius=1), NgonPoints(nsides=4, radius=.5))


test <- ggplot(data=twosquares, mapping=aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio=1)+
  xlim(-1,1)+
  ylim(-1,1)+
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())

#this traces the correct path
test <- test + geom_path()
test
#but this fills the inside of the inner square
test <- test + geom_polygon(alpha=.5)
test
```

[image: plot results]

Comment: Great question and great title!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The outer square is orientated counterclockwise:

```
twosquares$id <- seq_len(nrow(twosquares))
ggplot(data=twosquares, mapping=aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=id))
```

Therefore, you have to orientate the inner square clockwise in order to avoid filling it:

```
ggplot(data=twosquares[c(1:6,9,8,7,10), ], mapping=aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_polygon()
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I don't exactly understand the reason for this but I'm just going to roll with it.

Comment: Orientation is the only thing that allows distinguishing the parts of a polygon to be filled in an overlapping polygon or in a polygon with holes. You could easily add a smaller square inside your donut by orientating the new points CCW again.